# SharePoint Online User Profile not synced with User Information List

Tags: synchronization, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-userprofile, user-information-list

We have few users whose work email listed in User Profile Properties not synced with User Information List.

Initially, We added one user and his details to User Profile Properties. And we added the user to 'Assigned To' field of a list. There was a workflow to send email to the user. But the email value turned out to be null.

So when we checked User Information List (from site collection), his work email was seen missing in the list.

And we also found work email missing for some other users too.

Microsoft support said normally it will take 8 hours to 1 week for sync. But it's been a week since we added the user. Is there any method to sync these User Profile Properties and User Information List explicitly?

I have found some methods for syncing for SharePoint servers such as:

```
Stsadm.exe –o sync –listolddatabases 0
```

But I guess, we can't use it in SharePoint Online.

So is there any method to sync these User Profile Properties and User Information List in SharePoint Online (Office 365)?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Same here. Also the profile pictures of users are (suddenly) not visible anymore.

Comment: Here says you have to update another value to null clear some attribute... https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sposupport/2017/10/17/null-changes-do-not-get-updated-to-sharepoint-onlines-user-profile-application/